# PHP-FPM slows down after a while - Opcache File Cache

Tags: php, nginx, pagespeed-insights, opcache

My set up is a large drupal website with 50,000 requests per day. My main issue is that Php-fpm slows down after 10-15 minutes of a restart (1500+ code files). Cache is only full 40% (174mb of 512mb). Initial server response time is over 700ms but goes down to 170ms for first few minutes of a restart as per Google site speed testing.

I found this answer with similar issue and have added Opcache file cache with some improvement.
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/php-fpm-restart-necessary-for-site-speed.650549/#post-2654105

Current Opcache Settings

```
 [opcache]
    opcache.enable=1
    opcache.memory_consumption=512
    opcache.interned_strings_buffer=64
    opcache.max_accelerated_files=50000
    opcache.max_wasted_percentage=15
    opcache.validate_timestamps=0
    opcache.revalidate_freq=0
    opcache.mmap_base=0x20000000
    opcache.file_cache='var/www/cache'
    opcache.file_cache_fallback=1
```

Any other ideas on how to optimise the above to achieve consistent php-fpm performance. (Set up is Php-fpm 7.2, Nginx, Drupal, Mariadb on AWS server with 64G memory)

Tried adding File cache. It has shaved off 100ms but probably a lot more can be done.

Comment: We have the same issue. Trying to find the root-cause analysis.  Completely different environment though (apache/php-fpm 8.1,laravel,mysql rds). I see a lack of a slash on your file_cache though.. should it not be /var/www/cache ?

Comment: Thanks - it appear issue was when copy/pasted the code. It's fine on the server. Opcache slow down still remains a mystery.

Comment: We are trying to isolate.  Found that rebooting speeds up / but only for a short time. Restarting opcache/fpm slows a fresh reboot down immediately - and we know what the slow down is - in our case, it increases the number of file metadata requests by 1000% - but we do not know the cause.

Comment: Did you try using Filecache? In our case, it helps a lot.

Comment: I think our issues may be different?  We tried filecache - but it mitigating only a little and the main culprit - the massive uptick of file metadata requests - was unchanged.

Comment: Changing events.mechanism = epoll has apparently fixed this for us.

Comment: Our issue turned out to be a kernel bug (cf. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459450/surprising-slowdown-with-apache-nfs-on-ubuntu-22-04-2/1460599#1460599)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of trial and error, I think I have found the issue and it's solved now.

It was quite unrelated to Opcache. The real issue was that I had `pm.max_requests`set to handle 5000 requests which was causing memory leaks.

Changed it to 200 requests and increased `pm.max_children` other values.

This way each child gets respawned after 200 requests and any slow processes don't linger on. I was running Cron every 15 minutes which was particularly problematic in terms of memory leak.

Comment: Mark your answer as selected answer if it solved your problem.